# Can't find persitence Unit with Arquillian

Tags: jpa, glassfish, jboss-arquillian

I have a unit test set up with Arquillian and a remote Glassfish instance:

```
@RunWith(Arquillian.class)
public class ClientTest {

    @EJB
    private ClientService client;

    @Deployment
    public static Archive<?> createDeployment() {

           return ShrinkWrap.create(WebArchive.class, "test.war")
                   .addPackage(Client.class.getPackage())
                   .addPackage(ClientService.class.getPackage())
                   .addPackage(Client_.class.getPackage())
                   .addAsResource("test-persistence.xml", "META-INF/persistence.xml")
                   .addAsWebInfResource(EmptyAsset.INSTANCE, "beans.xml");
    }

    @Test
    public void testCreate() {
        Assert.assertNotNull("Client not null", client);
        Client c = client.getClientById(1L);
        assertNotNull(c);
    }
```

My persistence.xml looks as follows (works with development code)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="primary">
        <jta-data-source>jdbc/ora</jta-data-source>
        <properties>
            <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="FINEST" />
            <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="none"/> 
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

The data-source is configured on the remote glassfish-server. However I always get the following exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to retrieve EntityManagerFactory for unitName null
```

Answer (score 1):

you can directly point to your persistence.xml file from your source too.

```
.addAsResource("META-INF/persistence.xml")
```

that should alleviate your issues.

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
.addAsResource("test-persistence.xml", "META-INF/persistence.xml")
```

tells Shrinkwrap to look for a test-persistence.xml file inside your test/resources folder and add it to your war file inside META-INF folder.

You must rename the persistence.xml file to test-persistence.xml and make sure that it is available in your test/resources folder

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your questions. The `persistence.xml` was correctly deployed - I double checked it. The solution was to restart my glassfish server. Don't know why but after a restart everything worked fine.